# Azure Function ServiceBus Trigger Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have been trying to implement DI for Azure Functions where the functions is triggered by ServiceBus (topics/subscriptions in this case):

```
[Singleton]
[FunctionName("Alert")]
public static async Task Alert([ServiceBusTrigger(Topic.Alert, Subscription.PowerBi, Connection = "servicebusconnectionstring")] Message message, [Inject]IPowerBiService powerBiService, [Inject]IQueueService queueService)
```

I have read about Azure Functions and DI on following sites:

- https://mcguirev10.com/2018/04/03/service-locator-azure-functions-v2.html
- https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/
- https://github.com/introtocomputerscience/azure-function-autofac-dependency-injection

All examples works fins using HTTP trigger, I assume the IIS host is up and running and is containing the services. But using ServiceBus trigger, I can't get it to work. I have implemented the solutions mention above, and a few more but all get same issues. The code works, bu the services are created for message/trigger.

Anyone out there that has manage to do this, or arn't it possible to do?

NOTE (update):
I got some more information that I haven’t got time to verify yet, but I have been using a consumption plan for my Azure Functions. It may be the case that you need an App Service Plan instead (using consumption since that price model is more convenient). If anyone know more about this?
I will look into this later this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to confirm that it work’s fine now using an App Service Plan instead of an Consumption Plan. The difference is the "cold start" instead of a "warm" host.

I guess all different once of DI implementations should work fine. 
I have been using following : https://github.com/MV10/Azure.FunctionsV2.Service.Locator